# The changes which I made in mobile view are applying even for desktop view. How to avoid it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using HTML and bootstrap for nav menu. IN mobile view, I need border for the drop-down list. But the border is shown even in desktop view. I dont want this to happen. How to avoid it?

```
<li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #1F6689; border-top:1px solid #1F6689"><!-- ngIf: loggedUser --><a style="margin-right: 100px;" data-ng-if="loggedUser" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                        <span class="fa fa-user iconAlign font-icon-size">&nbsp;</span>Shrivatsav, Deeksha</a><!-- end ngIf: loggedUser -->
                    </li>
```

Please help.

Comment: use css class instead of inline style and add [media query](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy this into your stylesheet

```
@media (min-width:1200px){

.nav.navbar-nav > li
{
border:0 !important;
}

}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you included an explanation of what it does. Why do you need to use `!important`?

Comment: !important will override the inline style and activates the one given under the media query once when the browser width becomes larger than 1200px

Answer (score 0):

As @Vanojx1 commented, you should use a css class in stead of inline style. Inline css is always applied, independent of device.

I recommend using a .css file in stead of inline, it gives you a better overview of the layout and you can use media queries, which allow you to seperate desktop from tablet and mobile.

The w3schools site has some good examples to start with:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Happy coding!